# num_vertexが使えない理由がわからない

Tags: julia

複雑ネットワーク入門です。
公式サイトに書いてある、パッケージをインストールしで、同じコードを書いているのですがエラーがでてしまいます。理由がわからないです。。。

```
using Graphs
using GraphPlot
nodelabel = [1:num_vertices(g)]
gplot(g, nodelabel=nodelabel)

UndefVarError: num_vertics not defined

Stacktrace:  [1] top-level scope at In[53]:2
```

初歩的な質問で、躓いてしまっています。ご教授のほどお願いします。

Comment: `UndefVarError: num_vertics not defined`というエラーメッセージは、そのままコピーしたものですか。`num_vertics`は、スペルが間違っています。

Comment: コード自体はそのままオフィシャルサイトからコピーしました。エラーはそうです。あ、verticesですね。。。